# How grow a text area height on top when it overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I found the code below but the text area height grows at the bottom.

[backspace increases value of scrollheight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543526/backspace-increases-value-of-scrollheight)

How could I grow it from top to up direction?

It is for a chat application I am building, and this would be the typing area.

I spent some time on the net looking for the solution but it apparently is not that easy.

Edit: Looking at how the snipped behaves here in stackoverflow, I am thinking now that it may be related with how the parent wrapper is set on css, but still do not know how to fix it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach( element => {
  element.style.height = `${element.scrollHeight}px`;
  element.addEventListener('input', event => {
    event.target.style.height = 'auto'; 
    event.target.style.height = `${event.target.scrollHeight}px`;
  })
})
```

```css
/* style.css */
main, header {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

textarea {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-style: hidden;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.1em;
  margin: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale="1.0" />
  <title>Data Management</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="module" src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Growing textarea</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p><textarea class="data p" id="article" ></textarea></p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For expanding the textarea to the top you can use `position:absolute` and `bottom: 0` in a container with `position:relative`. This way the text-area will always stick to the bottom of the container with `0` margin.

Also, you can set the default rows of the textarea to 1 to look like a text input when the text fits inside one line:

```html
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach( element => {
  element.style.height = `${element.scrollHeight}px`;
  element.addEventListener('input', event => {
    event.target.style.height = 'auto'; 
    event.target.style.height = `${event.target.scrollHeight}px`;
  })
})
```

```css
/* style.css */
main, header {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

textarea {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-style: hidden;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.1em;
  margin: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0
}

main{
  position: relative;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale="1.0" />
  <title>Data Management</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="module" src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Growing textarea</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <textarea rows="1" class="data p" id="article"></textarea>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but still grows from the bottom to below, not from top towards the up direction.

Comment: Yes, I got your question wrong at first. I revised the answer.

Comment: is there any way to align center vertically the textarea content?

Comment: You can change the `line-height` of the `text-area` to move it to the top or bottom a little (it's actually the space between horizontal lines of the text). But because the height is always adjusted to the number of lines there shouldn't be any excess space at the top or bottom.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent hours searching for a practical solution like that one.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.